# show $ \sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} | c_n | < \infty \implies F_N f \to f \text{ uniformly}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to show that :

> $$F_n f = \sum_N^N c_n e^{inx}$$ with $$c_n = \frac 1 {2 \pi }
>  \int^{\pi}_{- \pi} f(x) e^{-inx} dx $$
>   $f \in C^0 ( \mathbb R )$, $2 \pi$ periodic
>
> $$ \sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} | c_n | < \infty  \implies  F_N f \to f
>  \text{ uniformly}$$

how to do that ?

> I don't understand why in the correction, they are computing the
>  difference between $F_N$ and $F_M$. Are we trying to show that the
>  serie is Cauchy ? If it is, then what ? In the correction they are just saying that then $F_N f$ converges uniformly to a continuous function g define as the sum.
>  Moreover, at the end, they are calling $$g(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} | c_n |$$ in order to conclude that $f=g$ a.e.. Why do you need to do
>  that ? They then say that since g and f has the same Fourier coefficients, they are equal.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Can you provide more context (like the proof you've been given)?

Comment: i added the maximum I could. Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess you mean $g(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty c_ne^{2i\pi nx}$ (and not what you wrote). Now, you can extend a bit the result : you can change the hypothesis $f\in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$ by $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ (and $2\pi-$periodic). If $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|c_k|<\infty $ then your proof (modifying the function $g$ of course) shows that $f$ has a continuous representative, which is quite a strong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you prove this depends on what you already know. It  should be trivial  to verify that there is some function $g$ with $F_Nf\to g$ uniformly, and that it follows that $\hat g(k) = \hat f(k)$ for every $k$. Now if you've already shown that $\hat g = \hat f$ implies $g=f$ almost everywhere you're done - if you don't already know that then that's the not-entirely-trivial part.

Comment: f and g hat is the fourier serie? And could you extend the first argument please. Why such g exists please. That s what i don't understand

Comment: _Define_ $g(t)=\sum c_nr^{int}$. The fact that $\sum|c_n|<\infty$ shows that $F_Nf\to g$ uniformly.

Comment: Oh i see. Thx. That was the order of the arguments that was messed up in my head